# Can I check for usage of lombok.experimental.* annotations with ArchUnit?"

Tags: testing, junit, archunit

As the question suggests, how can I check for certain imports with archUnit.

So I want the test to fail, when the tested class itself imports lombok.experimental.*.

I understand how to check for packages and stuff like that, but the approach doesnt seem to work for imports. Any suggestions?

My Code:

```
package com.nikita.Nikitos;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.Test;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.noClasses;
import com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaClasses;
import com.tngtech.archunit.core.importer.ClassFileImporter;

public class AppTest
{
    @Test
    public void keineKlassenAusLombokExperimental() {

        JavaClasses classes = new ClassFileImporter()
                .importPackages("com.nikita..");

        noClasses().should().dependOnClassesThat()
        .resideInAPackage("lombok.experimental..").check(classes);

    }

}
```

The class that I want to test:

```
package com.nikita.Nikitos;

import lombok.experimental.UtilityClass;

@UtilityClass
public class App
{
static int hd;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) acts as an annotation processor that modifies your class.

In case of [`@lombok.experimental.UtilityClass`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/UtilityClass) (and probably other lombok annotations as well), the final byte code doesn't actually contain the annotation anymore:

```java
@lombok.experimental.UtilityClass
public class App {
    static int hd;
}
```

is compiled (transformed) to

```
public final class App
  flags: (0x0031) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_FINAL, ACC_SUPER
  this_class: #5                          // App
  super_class: #6                         // java/lang/Object
  interfaces: 0, fields: 1, methods: 1, attributes: 1
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #6.#15         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = Class              #16            // java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException
   #3 = String             #17            // This is a utility class and cannot be instantiated
   #4 = Methodref          #2.#18         // java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   #5 = Class              #19            // App
   #6 = Class              #20            // java/lang/Object
   #7 = Utf8               hd
   #8 = Utf8               I
   #9 = Utf8               <init>
  #10 = Utf8               ()V
  #11 = Utf8               Code
  #12 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #13 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #14 = Utf8               App.java
  #15 = NameAndType        #9:#10         // "<init>":()V
  #16 = Utf8               java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException
  #17 = Utf8               This is a utility class and cannot be instantiated
  #18 = NameAndType        #9:#21         // "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #19 = Utf8               App
  #20 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
  #21 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/String;)V
{
  static int hd;
    descriptor: I
    flags: (0x0008) ACC_STATIC

  private App();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: (0x0002) ACC_PRIVATE
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: new           #2                  // class java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException
         7: dup
         8: ldc           #3                  // String This is a utility class and cannot be instantiated
        10: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        13: athrow
      LineNumberTable:
        line 4: 0
}
```

which could also have been produced from this plain Java code:

```java
public final class App {
    static int hd;

    private App() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This is a utility class and cannot be instantiated");
    }
}
```

If you want to detect such a pattern in the bytecode with ArchUnit, you'd probably have to reverse-engineer what Lombok does and e.g. search for private constructors in final classes that call the `UnsupportedOperationException(String)` constructor:

```java
ArchRule no_UtilityClass = noConstructors()
    .should().bePrivate()
    .andShould().beDeclaredInClassesThat().haveModifier(JavaModifier.FINAL)
    .andShould(new ArchCondition<JavaCodeUnit>("call new UnsupportedOperationException(String)") {
        @Override
        public void check(JavaCodeUnit codeUnit, ConditionEvents events) {
            boolean satisfied = codeUnit.getCallsFromSelf().stream().anyMatch(call ->
                    call.getTargetOwner().isEquivalentTo(UnsupportedOperationException.class)
                 && call.getName().equals(JavaConstructor.CONSTRUCTOR_NAME)
                 && call.getTarget().getRawParameterTypes().size() == 1
                 && call.getTarget().getRawParameterTypes().get(0).isEquivalentTo(String.class)
            );
            String message = String.format("%s %s `new UnsupportedOperationException(String)` in %s",
                    codeUnit.getDescription(), satisfied ? "calls" : "does not call", codeUnit.getSourceCodeLocation()
            );
            events.add(new SimpleConditionEvent(codeUnit, satisfied, message));
        }
    });
```

If you instead want to forbid the usage of `lombok.experimental.*` in the *source code*, you'll unfortunately need another tool; ArchUnit (currently) only analyzes *bytecode*.

Comment: if I understood everything correctly I can’t just disable all Lombok experimental features? So I have to do the process above for all anotations that Lombok.experimental offers?

Comment: ArchUnit only checks patterns in the _bytecode_. If you actually want to forbid the usage of `lombok.experimental.*` in the _source code,_ you'll unfortunately need another tool.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can you post an answer that writes that I need another tool, possibly with a link. Then I would mark it as the accepted answer 

Comment: I've extended this answer. By the way: maybe this question should be phrased _"Can I check for usage of lombok.experimental.* annotations with ArchUnit?"_

Comment: Changed it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

An import does not generate any signature in the bytecode, so ArchUnit cannot detect it directly.
Isn't it sufficient to check that your code does not depend on that package?

```java
ArchRule lombok_experimental_is_not_used = noClasses()
        .should().dependOnClassesThat().resideInAPackage("lombok.experimental..");
```

If you only wanted to detect the star import, then you unfortunately need to use another tool.

Comment: I ll add my code in the question, for me this approach doesnt seem to work, my test passes, even though it should throw an error

Comment: uploaded the code to the question 

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) acts as an annotation processor that modifies your class; the byte code doesn't actually contain the annotation any more.